# Why does this Cilk Array Notation matrix perform nearly twice as slow as the serial version?

Tags: arrays, caching, vectorization, matrix-multiplication, cilk-plus

I'm benchmarking matrix multiplication performance for serial and Cilk array notation versions.  The Cilk implementation takes nearly twice as long as the serial and I don't understand why.

**This is for single core execution**

This is the meat of the Cilk multiplication. Due to rank restrictions, I must store each multiplication in an array then `__sec_reduce_add` this array before setting the destination matrix element value.

```
int* sum = new int[VEC_SIZE];
for (int r = 0; (r < rowsThis); r++) {
    for (int c = 0; (c < colsOther); c++) {
        sum[0:VEC_SIZE] = myData[r][0:VEC_SIZE] * otherData[0:VEC_SIZE][c]; 
        product.data[r][c] = __sec_reduce_add(sum[0:VEC_SIZE]);
    }
}
```

I understand caching concerns and don't see any reason for the Cilk version to have fewer cache hits than the serial because they both access a column array that is hopefully in cache along with a series of misses for row elements.

Is there an obvious dependency that I'm overlooking or syntactic element of Cilk that I should be using? Should I be using Cilk in a different way to achieve maximum performance for non-block matrix multiplication using SIMD operations?

**I'm very new to Cilk so any help/suggestion is welcome.**

EDIT: 
Here's the serial implementation:

```
for (int row = 0; (row < rowsThis); row++) {
    for (int col = 0; (col < colsOther); col++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; (i < VEC_SIZE); i++)  {
            sum += (matrix1[row][i] * matrix2[i][col]);
        }
        matrix3[row][col] = sum;
    }
}
```

Memory is (de)allocated appropriately and multiplication results are correct for both implementations.  Matrix sizes are not known at compile time and a variety are used throughout the benchmark.

Compiler: icpc (ICC) 15.0.0 20140723 
Compile flags: icpc -g Wall -O2 -std=c++11

Ignore the use of allocated memory, conversion from vectors to vanilla arrays, etc.  I hacked apart another program to run this on a hunch assuming it'd be simpler than it in fact turned out to be. I couldn't get the compiler to accept cilk notation on both dimensions of the 2D vectors so I decided to use traditional arrays for the sake of the benchmark.

Here are all the appropriate files: 
MatrixTest.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Matrix.h"


#define MATRIX_SIZE 2000
#define REPETITIONS 1

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    auto init = [](int row, int col) { return row + col; };

    const Matrix matrix1(MATRIX_SIZE, MATRIX_SIZE, init);
    const Matrix matrix2(MATRIX_SIZE, MATRIX_SIZE, init);
    for (size_t i = 0; (i < REPETITIONS); i++) {
        const Matrix matrix3 = matrix1 * matrix2;
        std::cout << "Diag sum: " << matrix3.sumDiag() << std::endl;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Matrix.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using TwoDVec = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;

class Matrix {                                                                                                                                                                     
public:                                                                                                                                                                            
    Matrix();                                                                                                                                                                      
    ~Matrix();                                                                                                                                                                     
    Matrix(int rows, int cols);                                                                                                                                                    
    Matrix(int rows, int cols, std::function<Val(int, int)> init);                                                                                                                 
    Matrix(const Matrix& src);                                                                                                                                                     
    Matrix(Matrix&& src);                                                                                                                                                          
    Matrix operator*(const Matrix& src) const throw(std::exception);                                                                                                               
    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& src);                                                                                                                                          
    int sumDiag() const;                                                                                                                                                           

 protected:                                                                                                                                                                        
    int** getRawData() const;                                                                                                                                                      
 private:                                                                                                                                                                          
    TwoDVec data;                                                                                                                                                                  
};

#endif
```

Matrix.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Matrix.h"

#if defined(CILK)

Matrix
Matrix::operator*(const Matrix& other) const throw(std::exception) {
    int rowsOther = other.data.size();
    int colsOther = rowsOther > 0 ? other.data[0].size() : 0;
    int rowsThis = data.size();
    int colsThis = rowsThis > 0 ? data[0].size() : 0;
    if (colsThis != rowsOther) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid matrices for multiplication.");
    }

    int** thisRaw = this->getRawData();  // held until d'tor
    int** otherRaw = other.getRawData();

    Matrix product(rowsThis, colsOther);

    const int VEC_SIZE = colsThis;

    for (int r = 0; (r < rowsThis); r++) {
        for (int c = 0; (c < colsOther); c++) {
            product.data[r][c] = __sec_reduce_add(thisRaw[r][0:VEC_SIZE]
                                             * otherRaw[0:VEC_SIZE][c]);
        }
    }
    delete[] thisRaw;
    delete[] otherRaw;

    return product;
}

#elif defined(SERIAL)

Matrix
Matrix::operator*(const Matrix& other) const throw(std::exception) {
    int rowsOther = other.data.size();
    int colsOther = rowsOther > 0 ? other.data[0].size() : 0;
    int rowsThis = data.size();
    int colsThis = rowsThis > 0 ? data[0].size() : 0;
    if (colsThis != rowsOther) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid matrices for multiplication.");
    }

    int** thisRaw = this->getRawData();  // held until d'tor
    int** otherRaw = other.getRawData();

    Matrix product(rowsThis, colsOther);

    const int VEC_SIZE = colsThis;

    for (int r = 0; (r < rowsThis); r++) {
        for (int c = 0; (c < colsOther); c++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; (i < VEC_SIZE); i++) {
                sum += (thisRaw[r][i] * otherRaw[i][c]);
            }
            product.data[r][c] = sum;
        }
    }
    delete[] thisRaw;
    delete[] otherRaw;

    return product;
}

#endif

//  Default c'tor
Matrix::Matrix()
    : Matrix(1,1) { }

Matrix::~Matrix() { }

// Rows/Cols c'tor
Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    : data(TwoDVec(rows, std::vector<int>(cols, 0))) { }

//  Init func c'tor
Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols, std::function<int(int, int)> init)
    : Matrix(rows, cols) {
    for (int r = 0; (r < rows); r++) {
        for (int c = 0; (c < cols); c++) {
            data[r][c] = init(r,c);
        }
    }
}

//  Copy c'tor
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& other) {
    int rows = other.data.size();
    int cols = rows > 0 ? other.data[0].size() : 0;
    this->data.resize(rows, std::vector<int>(cols, 0));
    for(int r = 0; (r < rows); r++) {
        this->data[r] = other.data[r];
    }
}


//  Move c'tor
Matrix::Matrix(Matrix&& other) {
    if (this == &other) return;
    this->data.clear();
    int rows = other.data.size();
    for (int r = 0; (r < rows); r++) {
        this->data[r] = std::move(other.data[r]);
    }
}


Matrix&
Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& other) {
    int rows = other.data.size();
    this->data.resize(rows, std::vector<int>(0));
    for (int r = 0; (r < rows); r++) {
        this->data[r] = other.data[r];
    }
    return *this;
}

int
Matrix::sumDiag() const {
    int rows = data.size();
    int cols = rows > 0 ? data[0].size() : 0;

    int dim = (rows < cols ? rows : cols);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; (i < dim); i++) {
        sum += data[i][i];
    }
    return sum;
}


int**
Matrix::getRawData() const {
    int** rawData = new int*[data.size()];
    for (int i = 0; (i < data.size()); i++) {
        rawData[i] = const_cast<int*>(data[i].data());
    }
    return rawData;
}
```

Comment: How big is VEC_SIZE and what compiler are you using?  What does the serial code look like?

Comment: How big is rowsThis and colsOther?  Is VEC_SIZE a constant?  Did you remember to free the temporary array created with "new int[VEC_SIZE]"?

Comment: I've made the appropriate edits.  Does compile time awareness of matrix sizes offer improved optimization opportunity for these Cilk operations?

Comment: The sizes might have cache effects.  For example, the temporary array sum might spill out of L1 cache if VEC_SIZE is big.

Comment: Another question: are C99 variable length arrays involved?  I.e. is the last dimension of each matrix a compile-time constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated 2015-3-30 to match long code examples.]

icc is probably auto-vectorizing your accumulation loop, so the Cilk Plus is competing against vectorized code.  There are two possible performance problems here:

1. The temporary array sum increases the number of loads and stores.  The serial code is doing only two (SIMD) loads and almost no stores per (SIMD) multiplication.  With the temporary array, there are three loads and one store per multiplication.
2. matrix2 has a non-unit-stride access pattern (in the serial code too).  Typical current hardware works much better with unit stride accesses.

To fix problem (1), eliminate the temporary array, as you later did in the longer samples.  E.g.:

```
for (int r = 0; (r < rowsThis); r++) {
    for (int c = 0; (c < colsOther); c++) {
        product.data[r][c] = __sec_reduce_add(thisRaw[r][0:VEC_SIZE] * otherRaw[0:VEC_SIZE][c]);
    }
}
```

The rank of the result of `__sec_reduce_add` is zero, and so is okay to assign to a scalar.

Better yet, fix the stride problem.  Unless the result matrix is very wide, a good way to do that is to accumulate results by row, like this:

```
for (int r = 0; (r < rowsThis); r++) {
    product.data[r].data()[0:colsOther] = 0;
    for (int k = 0; (k < VEC_SIZE); k++) {
        product.data[r].data()[0:colsOther] +=thisRaw[r][k] * otherRaw[k][0:colsOther];
    }
}
```

Note the use of `data()` here.  Array notation currently does not allow section notation to be used with overloaded `[]` from `std::vector`.  So I used `data()`to get a pointer to the underlying data, which I can use with array notation.

Now the array sections all have unit stride, and so the compiler can use the vector hardware efficiently.  The scheme above is usually my favorite way to structure an unblocked matrix multiplication.  When compiled with `icpc -g -Wall -O2 -xHost -std=c++11 -DCILK` and run on an i7-4770 processor, I saw the MatrixTest program time fall from about 52 sec to 1.75 sec, a 29x performance improvement.

The code can be simplified and sped up a little more by eliminating the zeroing (which is already done when `product` is constructed), and eliminating construction of the temporary pointer arrays.  Here is a complete definition of the revised operator*:

```
Matrix
Matrix::operator*(const Matrix& other) const throw(std::exception) {
    int rowsOther = other.data.size();
    int colsOther = rowsOther > 0 ? other.data[0].size() : 0;
    int rowsThis = data.size();
    int colsThis = rowsThis > 0 ? data[0].size() : 0;
    if (colsThis != rowsOther) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid matrices for multiplication.");
    }

    Matrix product(rowsThis, colsOther);

    for (int r = 0; (r < rowsThis); r++) {
        product.data[r].data()[0:colsOther] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; (k < colsThis); k++) {
            product.data[r].data()[0:colsOther] += (*this).data[r][k] * other.data[k].data()[0:colsOther];
        }
    }

    return product;
}
```

The long line would be shorter if `Matrix` had a method for computing `data[i].data()`.

Comment: Ok I tried the first example and still saw much slower performance. I've confirmed the integrity of the benchmark and supplied compile time constants for matrix sizes.  I'm confused by your second example.

Comment: Is it practical for you to post the complete benchmark?  What compiler (and version thereof) are you using?

Comment: I cut out unrelated methods and added the files above.

Comment: Matrix.h references a "Val.h" that is undefined.  icc tip: Add "-xHost" to the command line if you are running on the same platform as you are compiling.  That way you get AVX if your platform has it, without any overhead for CPUID checks.

Comment: I can't replicate the slowdown.  Here's a run on a Haswell processor:

$ make

icpc -g -Wall -O2 -xHost -std=c++11 -DSERIAL Matrix.cpp MatrixTest.cpp -o s.x

icpc -g -Wall -O2 -xHost -std=c++11 -DCILK Matrix.cpp MatrixTest.cpp -o c.x

time s.x

Diag sum: 1922000768

52.56user 0.01system 0:52.56elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 48356maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+12176minor)pagefaults 0swaps
time c.x

Diag sum: 1922000768

52.41user 0.00system 0:52.40elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 48360maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+12178minor)pagefaults 0swaps

Comment: Yesterday I updated my answer to show the second solution using the conventions of the long example.  It runs much faster than the original code.